# Multi-variate time series forecasting with Python

Tags: time-series, python, forecasting

I have the following min-max normalized 2D dataset:

[image]

The actual dataset has **32 features + y**, and several thousand instances (features 1-5 start having different values further down the line).

I plan to forecast `y` using [`sktime`](https://www.sktime.org/en/latest/). What would be the best pipeline to accomplish this?

And is machine learning the best way to work with this data or would deep learning work better(LSTM)?

If you have experience solving this problem with a greater than 89% accuracy using whichever algorithm (including evolutionary algos) and are willing to help, we will greatly appreciate that.

Comment: I've deleted this comment thread because it has devolved into bickering. I refer all participants to the code of conduct: https://stats.stackexchange.com/conduct as a reminder for how users are expected to comport themselves.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a comprehensive answer in one of [sktime's issues](https://github.com/alan-turing-institute/sktime/issues/197#issuecomment-567941326), specifically:

> - event modelling (because the "condition" happens rarely, and there are many days in-between without)
> - with exogeneous variables (= weather etc) that of are time series type

They offer suggestions on how to go about it, which I'll follow.